Oracle SQL_Macro and analytic functions
The following SQL Macro returns all (three) rows or just one, depending on P_ID parameter. Logic consists in basic appended records and an analytic LAG function:
create or replace function Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID in integer) return clob sql_macro is
begin
  return 'select * 
            from (select ID, lag(ID, 1) over (order by ID) as Prev_ID
                    from (select 1 ID from dual union all 
                          select 2 ID from dual union all 
                          select 3 ID from dual))
           where ID = nvl(P_ID, ID)';
end Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M;

Example of all rows:
select * from Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => null) order by ID;




ID
PREV_ID




1



2
1


3
2



Example of only one row:
select * from Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => 2) order by ID;




ID
PREV_ID




2
1



But instead of passing P_ID directly, suppose it's taken from another query:
with P as (select 2 P_ID from dual) -- this could be way more complex...
select M.*
  from P, Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => P.P_ID) M




ID
PREV_ID




2
1



So  far, so good!
Now, I'm going to change the macro logic but ignore its details (i.e. having the LAG on a filtered one row subset is not useful...):
create or replace function Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID in integer) return clob sql_macro is
begin
  return 'select ID, lag(ID, 1) over (order by ID) as Prev_ID
            from (select 1 ID from dual union all 
                  select 2 ID from dual union all 
                  select 3 ID from dual)
           where ID = nvl(P_ID, ID)';
end Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M;

The following is correctly returning a record (forget the logic!):
with P as (select 2 P_ID from dual)
select M.ID --,M.Prev_ID --> if you add this field, then macro returns all rows instead of filtering
  from P, Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => P.P_ID) M

The following instead returns the full set:
with P as (select 2 P_ID from dual)
select M.ID, M.Prev_ID --> if you add this field, then macro returns all rows instead of filtering
  from P, Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => P.P_ID) M

fiddle
I believe the query should always return only one record, regardless of which fields are selected.
Workaround by MT0:
with P as (select 2 P_ID from dual)
select M.ID, M.Prev_ID
  from P
cross join lateral (select * from Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => P.P_ID)) M


This is a bug, and seems to be fixed in the latest version (23.4)

@gsalem do you have a bug reference? I'd like to ask backporting to 19.22 I'm actually using.

It does reproduce in 21c - you have to use the second macro, without the extra level on subquery.

This appears to be an issue related to using generated data - if P is a table then the issue is not appearing in my (limited) tests. If P is created using SELECT 2 FROM DUAL then the issue sometimes appears (and sometimes doesn't) fiddle

Still sometimes works if P is a table and does not work for SELECT 2 FROM DUAL fiddle (and does not appear to be related to analytic functions as it also appears when using a hierarchical function and no analytics) - This looks like a bug.

I said it is a bug because it looks very much like one. I tried it on a newer 23 version and it works.

Work around: wrap the macro in LATERAL
lateral( select * from Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(PID => P.P_ID)) M


The work-around appears to be less about the LATERAL keyword and more about using SELECT * FROM .... If you use CROSS APPLY Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(PID => P.P_ID) then the bug still occurs but CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM Test_SQL_Macro_Analytic_M(P_ID => P.P_ID)) it doesn't. A LATERAL join happens to be syntactically invalid without the SELECT. fiddle

interesting indeed
